# Lablgtk motion_notify event doesn't work

Tags: gtk, ocaml, lablgtk

I want to implement drawing area that responds with some action when the mouse click within area. So i connected to `motion_notify` event, but nothing happen when mouse button is clicked.
Here is example code:

File graph.ml

```
open GObj
class gridViewCanvas ?width ?height ?packing ?show rows cols =

  let vbox = GPack.vbox ?width ?height ?packing ?show () in

  let da = GMisc.drawing_area ~packing:vbox#add () in
  let drawable = lazy (new GDraw.drawable da#misc#window) in

  object (self)
    inherit widget vbox#as_widget

    initializer
      ignore(da#event#connect#expose
          ~callback: (fun _ -> self#repaint (); false));
      ignore(da#event#connect#motion_notify
          ~callback: (fun _ -> prerr_endline "OK"; false))

    method private drawGrid drawable =
      let (width, height) = drawable#size in
      let cellWidth = float_of_int width /. float_of_int cols in
      let cellHeight = float_of_int height /. float_of_int rows in

      drawable#set_foreground `BLACK;
      let currHeight : float ref = ref 0. in
      for i = 0 to rows - 1 do
        drawable#line ~x: 0 ~y: (int_of_float !currHeight)
                      ~x: width ~y: (int_of_float !currHeight);
        currHeight := !currHeight +. cellHeight;
      done;

      let currWidth : float ref = ref 0. in
      for i = 0 to cols - 1 do
        drawable#line ~x: (int_of_float !currWidth) ~y: 0
                      ~x: (int_of_float !currWidth) ~y: height;
        currWidth := !currWidth +. cellWidth;
      done;
      ()

    method private repaint () =
     let drawable = Lazy.force drawable in
     let (width, height) = drawable#size in
     drawable#set_foreground `WHITE;
     drawable#rectangle ~x:0 ~y:0 ~width ~height ~filled:true ();

     self#drawGrid drawable
end
```

File test.ml

```
open GMain
open GdkKeysyms
open Graph

let locale = GtkMain.Main.init ()

let main () =
  let window = GWindow.window ~width:640 ~height:480
                          ~title:"Title" () in
  let vbox = GPack.vbox ~packing:window#add () in
  window#connect#destroy ~callback:Main.quit;

  let menubar = GMenu.menu_bar ~packing:vbox#pack () in
  let factory = new GMenu.factory menubar in
  let accel_group = factory#accel_group in
  let file_menu = factory#add_submenu "File" in

  let factory = new GMenu.factory file_menu ~accel_group in
  factory#add_item "Quit" ~key:_Q ~callback: Main.quit;

  let graph = new gridViewCanvas ~packing:vbox#add 5 3 in

  window#show ();
  Main.main ()

let () =
  main ()
```

compiling with
`ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg graph.ml test.ml -o graphtest`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the sensitivity of your widget to events is not set.
Your widget will come to live if you add the following line after the initializer clause :

```
            da#event#add[`ALL_EVENTS];
```

Much more events are available, and you provide the list of the events to which your widget will be sensitive.